# Docker Swarm nodes on different subnets

Tags: vpn, docker, kubernetes, subnet, docker-swarm

I'm trying to setup a docker swarm between two computers I have at home and a VPS, the configuration is the following:

```
Manager ip:         192.168.1.132/24
Manager second ip:  192.168.100.1/24 (VPN)
First node ip:      192.168.1.131/24
Second node ip:     192.168.100.2/24 (VPN)
```

For creating the swarm I used `docker swarm init --listen-addr 0.0.0.0:2377` on the manager, and for connecting the first node I used `docker swarm join --token TOKEN 192.168.100.1:2377`.

When I type `docker swarm join --token TOKEN 192.168.100.1:2377` on the second node, it connects to the manager but after a short period of time it goes into *Down* state.

Some replicated services are working but I'm not pretty sure (i.e. portainer doesn't show the second node correctly).

I tried removing the VPN but obviously the result was the same.
I haven't tried connecting the fist node into the vpn since I think it will just add network overhead.
The docker logs of the second node are the following:

```
" level=error msg="Failed to join memberlist [192.168.1.132] on retry: 1 error occurred:\n\t* Failed to join 192.168.1.132:7946: dial tcp 192.168.1.132:7946: i/o timeout\n\n"
" level=error msg="agent: session failed" backoff=1.5s error="session initiation timed out" module=node/agent node.id=zc5n9lf9337oxotcdzdmnwcyt
" level=info msg="manager selected by agent for new session: {v4qwwathmfq02g6pcg267bftu 192.168.1.132:2377}" module=node/agent node.id=zc5n9lf9337oxotcdzdmnwcyt
" level=info msg="waiting 887.467138ms before registering session" module=node/agent node.id=zc5n9lf9337oxotcdzdmnwcyt
" level=error msg="agent: session failed" backoff=3.1s error="session initiation timed out" module=node/agent node.id=zc5n9lf9337oxotcdzdmnwcyt
" level=info msg="manager selected by agent for new session: {v4qwwathmfq02g6pcg267bftu 192.168.1.132:2377}" module=node/agent node.id=zc5n9lf9337oxotcdzdmnwcyt
" level=info msg="waiting 3.079456527s before registering session" module=node/agent node.id=zc5n9lf9337oxotcdzdmnwcyt
" level=error msg="agent: session failed" backoff=6.3s error="session initiation timed out" module=node/agent node.id=zc5n9lf9337oxotcdzdmnwcyt
" level=info msg="manager selected by agent for new session: {v4qwwathmfq02g6pcg267bftu 192.168.1.132:2377}" module=node/agent node.id=zc5n9lf9337oxotcdzdmnwcyt
" level=info msg="waiting 893.272869ms before registering session" module=node/agent node.id=zc5n9lf9337oxotcdzdmnwcyt
" level=error msg="Failed to join memberlist [192.168.1.132] on retry: 1 error occurred:\n\t* Failed to join 192.168.1.132:7946: dial tcp 192.168.1.132:7946: i/o timeout\n\n"
" level=error msg="agent: session failed" backoff=8s error="session initiation timed out" module=node/agent node.id=zc5n9lf9337oxotcdzdmnwcyt
" level=info msg="manager selected by agent for new session: {v4qwwathmfq02g6pcg267bftu 192.168.1.132:2377}" module=node/agent node.id=zc5n9lf9337oxotcdzdmnwcyt
" level=info msg="waiting 4.256079162s before registering session" module=node/agent node.id=zc5n9lf9337oxotcdzdmnwcyt
" level=error msg="agent: session failed" backoff=8s error="session initiation timed out" module=node/agent node.id=zc5n9lf9337oxotcdzdmnwcyt
" level=info msg="manager selected by agent for new session: {v4qwwathmfq02g6pcg267bftu 192.168.1.132:2377}" module=node/agent node.id=zc5n9lf9337oxotcdzdmnwcyt
" level=info msg="waiting 7.510543006s before registering session" module=node/agent node.id=zc5n9lf9337oxotcdzdmnwcyt
" level=error msg="agent: session failed" backoff=8s error="session initiation timed out" module=node/agent node.id=zc5n9lf9337oxotcdzdmnwcyt
" level=info msg="manager selected by agent for new session: {v4qwwathmfq02g6pcg267bftu 192.168.1.132:2377}" module=node/agent node.id=zc5n9lf9337oxotcdzdmnwcyt
" level=info msg="waiting 7.737578398s before registering session" module=node/agent node.id=zc5n9lf9337oxotcdzdmnwcyt
" level=error msg="agent: session failed" backoff=8s error="session initiation timed out" module=node/agent node.id=zc5n9lf9337oxotcdzdmnwcyt
" level=info msg="manager selected by agent for new session: {v4qwwathmfq02g6pcg267bftu 192.168.1.132:2377}" module=node/agent node.id=zc5n9lf9337oxotcdzdmnwcyt
" level=info msg="waiting 4.645359575s before registering session" module=node/agent node.id=zc5n9lf9337oxotcdzdmnwcyt
" level=error msg="agent: session failed" backoff=8s error="session initiation timed out" module=node/agent node.id=zc5n9lf9337oxotcdzdmnwcyt
" level=info msg="manager selected by agent for new session: {v4qwwathmfq02g6pcg267bftu 192.168.1.132:2377}" module=node/agent node.id=zc5n9lf9337oxotcdzdmnwcyt
" level=info msg="waiting 6.610075508s before registering session" module=node/agent node.id=zc5n9lf9337oxotcdzdmnwcyt
" level=info msg="NetworkDB stats vmi361639.contaboserver.net(0b1769452f24) - netID:5selpdsjctbeu6hyvhk13pp2w leaving:false netPeers:1 entries:2 Queue qLen:0 netMsg/s:0"
" level=info msg="NetworkDB stats vmi361639.contaboserver.net(0b1769452f24) - netID:tlwdansnqedavybolyklvlf54 leaving:true netPeers:0 entries:3 Queue qLen:0 netMsg/s:0"
" level=error msg="agent: session failed" backoff=8s error="session initiation timed out" module=node/agent node.id=zc5n9lf9337oxotcdzdmnwcyt
" level=info msg="manager selected by agent for new session: {v4qwwathmfq02g6pcg267bftu 192.168.1.132:2377}" module=node/agent node.id=zc5n9lf9337oxotcdzdmnwcyt
" level=info msg="waiting 2.292767564s before registering session" module=node/agent node.id=zc5n9lf9337oxotcdzdmnwcyt
" level=error msg="Failed to join memberlist [192.168.1.132] on retry: 1 error occurred:\n\t* Failed to join 192.168.1.132:7946: dial tcp 192.168.1.132:7946: i/o timeout\n\n"
" level=error msg="agent: session failed" backoff=8s error="session initiation timed out" module=node/agent node.id=zc5n9lf9337oxotcdzdmnwcyt
" level=info msg="manager selected by agent for new session: {v4qwwathmfq02g6pcg267bftu 192.168.1.132:2377}" module=node/agent node.id=zc5n9lf9337oxotcdzdmnwcyt
" level=info msg="waiting 4.678195176s before registering session" module=node/agent node.id=zc5n9lf9337oxotcdzdmnwcyt
" level=error msg="agent: session failed" backoff=8s error="session initiation timed out" module=node/agent node.id=zc5n9lf9337oxotcdzdmnwcyt
" level=info msg="manager selected by agent for new session: {v4qwwathmfq02g6pcg267bftu 192.168.1.132:2377}" module=node/agent node.id=zc5n9lf9337oxotcdzdmnwcyt
" level=info msg="waiting 177.932719ms before registering session" module=node/agent node.id=zc5n9lf9337oxotcdzdmnwcyt
" level=error msg="agent: session failed" backoff=8s error="session initiation timed out" module=node/agent node.id=zc5n9lf9337oxotcdzdmnwcyt
" level=info msg="manager selected by agent for new session: {v4qwwathmfq02g6pcg267bftu 192.168.1.132:2377}" module=node/agent node.id=zc5n9lf9337oxotcdzdmnwcyt
" level=info msg="waiting 3.603526614s before registering session" module=node/agent node.id=zc5n9lf9337oxotcdzdmnwcyt
" level=error msg="agent: session failed" backoff=8s error="session initiation timed out" module=node/agent node.id=zc5n9lf9337oxotcdzdmnwcyt
" level=info msg="manager selected by agent for new session: {v4qwwathmfq02g6pcg267bftu 192.168.1.132:2377}" module=node/agent node.id=zc5n9lf9337oxotcdzdmnwcyt
" level=info msg="waiting 5.424952674s before registering session" module=node/agent node.id=zc5n9lf9337oxotcdzdmnwcyt
" level=info msg="shutting down certificate renewal routine" module=node/tls node.id=zc5n9lf9337oxotcdzdmnwcyt node.role=swarm-worker
" level=info msg="Node 0b1769452f24/192.168.100.2, left gossip cluster"
" level=info msg="Node 0b1769452f24 change state NodeActive --> NodeFailed"
" level=info msg="Node 0b1769452f24/192.168.100.2, added to failed nodes list"
```

(the output is truncated to show just the connection issues)
I'm considering to switch to Kubernetes but i don't know if it will effectively solve my problem.

What can I do?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What kind of VPN do you use? Docker Swarm needs to be on the same network

Comment: I used [Wireguard](https://www.wireguard.com/) to connect the second node to the manager.

Comment: I think you need to check the routing table to make sure that docker Swarm traffic goes over the vpn. That starts by connecting to the ip address of the VPN interface, instead of the regular eth0/eth1